# Sub-query results 'Single Row Sub-Query results more than One Row'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table `Office` created in SQL Terminal on Oracle 11g .

---

Whose 3 columns are 
`Ename | Bname  | salary` where:-
`Ename` : The name of the employer.
`Bname` : Boss Name 
`Salary` : Employee salary.

---

The values inside the `Office Table` are :-

```
ENAME                BNAME                    SALARY
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
Zahid                Muheet                    30000
Arif                 Muheet                    20002
Ahtishaam            Muheet                    20002
Ayaaz                Muheet                     2000
Zaid                 Muheet                    40000
Muheet               Akib                      40000

6 rows selected.
```

I want to retrieve all those employees name(`ename`) whose `salary` is greater or equal to his `boss` `salary`.

Output Should be:

```
ENAME
------
Zaid
```

I'm writing a query on my terminal

```
select emp.ename
from office emp
where emp.salary >= (select a.salary
                     from office a,
                          office b
                     where a.ename = b.bname)
```

I guess it should work but its resulting in error :

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Why Muheet is not in the result? He has higher salary than his boss Arif.

Comment: Are there only 1 entry per employee in this table or can there be many?

Comment: Is the data correct? Arif <-> Muheet are eachothers boss?

Comment: To avoid ambiguity I removed another arif from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select emp.ename 
from office emp 
where emp.salary>= ( select boss.salary 
                     from office boss 
                     where emp.bname = boss.ename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I am a C programmer. I wasnt not knowing that emp can be accessed  even inside the ( brackets scope).

Comment: @ZahidKhan the () reference only works 1 level removed.  This type of query is called a correlated subquery.

Comment: @nacho: surely!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join for this as well

```
select o1.ename 
from office o1
join office o2 on o1.ename = o2.bname
where o1.salary >= o2.salary
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN the table with itself:

```
SELECT
oa.ename
FROM office AS oa
INNER JOIN office AS ob ON oa.bname = ob.ename
WHERE oa.salary >= ob.salary;
```

This creates a result set where everyone's salary and name and their bosses salary and name are available, and then filters it by those where the employee salary is greater then or equal to the boss's salary.

In a case such as this one there is no need to use a subquery, but if you absolutely have to, there is a way using a subquery as well:

```
SELECT
oa.ename
FROM office AS oa
WHERE oa.salary >= (SELECT ob.salary FROM office AS ob WHERE ob.ename = oa.bname)
```

Comment: @XING TOP doesn't work in oracle?. Huh, apparently it doesn't. I'll change that momentarily.

Comment: should work just fine without the extra precaution of TOP as long as the database doesn't violate normalisation rules.

Comment: Still the answer you provided was already given by someone else so doesnot make sense to keep writing sam answer mutliple times. You can feel free to delete it.

Comment: @XING I gave multiple approaches to solve the problem and explained what it was doing while I was doing it. The other 2 answers are just code dumps, and are discouraged. I can't decide how you vote for you but I think this has value beyond that.

Comment: Well i can see both the version of your answers is already been answered. i would say you can add your thoughts as comment to those answer and vote them rather than keeping your version.

Comment: @XING Substantially editing another person's answer is discouraged, and comments are temporary. Generally the guidance is to downvote code-only answers, even if they are correct, but I don't really like downvoting these 2 since they solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

And a 3rd approach using exists and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT Emps.EName
FROM Office Emps
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Office Boss 
              WHERE Emps.BName = Boss.EName 
                and Emps.Salary >= Boss.Salary)
```